OneSignal node-api v5.0.0 include_players_ids field
Before I’ve been used onesignal-node-sdk in that way to specify targeting users.
It used to work in previous sdk version
const app = await this.oneSignalService.getApp(
        process.env["ONESIGNAL_APP_ID"]
      );
      const notificationOptions = new OneSignal.Notification();
      notificationOptions.app_id = app.id!;
      notificationOptions.name = NOTIFICATION.NAME;
      notificationOptions.is_ios = true;
      notificationOptions.is_android = true;
      notificationOptions.include_player_ids = players;
      notificationOptions.headings = headings;
      notificationOptions.contents = contents;
      const notification = await this.oneSignalService.createNotification(
        notificationOptions
      );

I'm passing array of users which need to receive notifications in that way using notificationOptions.include_player_ids = players;
After onesignal-node-sdk new release 5.0.0 that property notificationOptions.include_player_ids seems was removed.
OneSignal official docs on it website and npm is deprecated. The only one current is on github repo. But I didn't found there the way how to manage that case.
How am I able to make it now to targeting users notifications?
